Mac OS - Homebrew - Mysql won't start
I have reinstalled Mysql via homebrew on Mac OS Sonoma 14.6.1 and when I try to run:
sudo mysql.server start

I get the following error message:
2024-10-09T09:13:17.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/.err'.
2024-10-09T09:13:17.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2024-10-09T09:13:17.797714Z 0 [System] [MY-015015] [Server] MySQL Server - start.
2024-10-09T09:13:17.982937Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 9.0.1) starting as process 17933
2024-10-09T09:13:17.985396Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2024-10-09T09:13:17.993893Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-10-09T09:13:18.012828Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012592] [InnoDB] Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
2024-10-09T09:13:18.012865Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012593] [InnoDB] The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2024-10-09T09:13:18.012874Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012594] [InnoDB] If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2024-10-09T09:13:18.012884Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012646] [InnoDB] File ./ibdata1: 'open' returned OS error 71. Cannot continue operation
2024-10-09T09:13:18.012897Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012981] [InnoDB] Cannot continue operation.
2024-10-09T09:13:18.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/.pid ended
2024-10-09T09:13:21.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/.err'.
2024-10-09T09:13:21.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2024-10-09T09:13:21.271166Z 0 [System] [MY-015015] [Server] MySQL Server - start.
2024-10-09T09:13:21.454371Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 9.0.1) starting as process 18039  
2024-10-09T09:13:21.456889Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive  
2024-10-09T09:13:21.456917Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010123] [Server] Fatal error: Please read "Security"   section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!  
2024-10-09T09:13:21.457157Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting  
2024-10-09T09:13:21.457538Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 9.0.1) Homebrew.
2024-10-09T09:13:21.457543Z 0 [System] [MY-015016] [Server] MySQL Server - end.  
2024-10-09T09:13:21.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/.pid ended  

I have tried to reinstall it from scratch 3 times now. I have also tried to change ownership of /usr/local/var/mysql to mysql:mysql but that have not solved the problem. I have also tried to delete the folder /usr/local/var/mysql and all of its content before reinstalling mysql.
When I try to run:
sudo mysql.server start

With the old content of my mysql folder (not a fresh install), I get the following error:
2024-10-09T09:33:14.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/erik-mac.err'.   
2024-10-09T09:33:14.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql   
2024-10-09T09:33:14.811122Z 0 [System] [MY-015015] [Server] MySQL Server - start.   
2024-10-09T09:33:14.993247Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 9.0.1) starting as process 42946   
2024-10-09T09:33:14.995678Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive   
2024-10-09T09:33:14.995704Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010123] [Server] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!   
2024-10-09T09:33:14.995929Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting   
2024-10-09T09:33:14.996300Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 9.0.1)  Homebrew.   
2024-10-09T09:33:14.996304Z 0 [System] [MY-015016] [Server] MySQL Server - end.   
2024-10-09T09:33:15.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/erik-mac.pid ended   


have you tried reading what you pasted? Esp. ERROR things might give you some light

Of course, I have tried to reinstall it from scratch 3 times now. I have also tried to change ownership of /usr/local/var/mysql to mysql:mysql but that have not solved the problem. I have also tried to delete the folder /usr/local/var/mysql and all of its content before reinstalling mysql.

I downgraded to Mysql 8.4 and then manually started mysql server by using the command:

sudo /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld --user=root

This seemed to have solved my problem?

The instructions are clearly listed in Homebrew's usual caveats section. If that doesn't display on your machine, you need to find out why. Running brew doctor would be a good place to start.
If it does display and you just didn't bother to read it, you can display it again by running brew info mysql; it will display the information again without having to reinstall it.
In your situation:

Reset (or delete) all files and folders that you have changed ownership of
Run brew doctor and fix whatever it says - you may have forgotten something.
Do a brew reinstall mysql just to be sure
Read the complete output of that command!
Start mysql normally, for example by running brew services mysql start


I did try this multiple times, the command brew service mysql start also said that mysql started successfully but checking the logs, mysql did not start and was not running, even though brew said it did. I solved it by downgrading to mysql 8.4 and then manually ran:
sudo /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld --user=root

If you follow step 4 of my answer, you have learned how to attach it to your terminal. Why don't you do that and tell us what the output is, so we actually know what you're looking at beyond having tried it multiple times? No need for logs.
